# Terminating the current NSURLRequest in ResourceLoadDelegate orderly

Tags: cocoa, webkit

In a WebKit **ResourceLoadDelegate**, I implemented this method:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)webView:(WebView *)sender 
          resource:(id)identifier 
          willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
          redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse 
          fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource
```

The method performs certain checks regarding the source of the request, and needs to **kill certain requests**.

**Question**

Could you provide a way to **orderly cancel NSURLRequest** within ResourceLoadDelegate within the above method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I'd imagine returning nil would do it. If not, return an empty NSURLRequest that does nothing.